# Riddler: Matchstick Triangles

Tags: matches

Starting with an equilateral triangle with 4 matches on each side can you make 2 smaller equilateral triangles by moving just 4 matches? Then can you create 4 smaller Equilateral triangles by moving just 4 matches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
>  
>     _ _  _ _
>     \      /
>      \    /
>       \  /
>        \/
> ```
>
> 1. "Fold" the triangle in half, inverting the tip.
>
> ```
>  
>     _ _  _ _
>     \  /\  /
>      \/  \/
> ```
>
> 2. Do the same for the two smaller triangles.
>
> ```
>  
>      _ _  _ _
>      \/\/\/\/
> ```

Comment: Nice answer! :-)

Comment: I was just producing images for the same.

Comment: @prog_SAHIL - I think the key trick is to get the right answer in quickly, and then embellish it with images/formatting for clarity. The perfect is the enemy of the good.

Comment: @prog_SAHIL Sorry *(not really!)* I have added some ascii art now.